# Mac external monitor no scale option

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display

When I connect to a benq 4k 32 inch monitor,  there are 5 scale that I can choose.

However when connect to a dell 27 inch 2k monitor,  no scale options.    I change the resolution to lower but it just look weird.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

27" 2k isn't 'retina' or 'HiDPI'

The mac will only offer the Larger Text/More Space scale on a retina screen.

[image]

On a 'regular' screen you just get the old style 'resolutions' drop menu.

[image]

Comment: Their is workaround https://medium.com/@jrmorola/how-i-achieve-125-scaling-in-my-2k-ultrawide-monitor-in-mac-os-catalina-296ebcd19a9f

Comment: and anonther https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay